# mixing joined and single table inheritance and querying for all objects

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a webapp that is working with the following configuration (I changed the entity names):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "animals")
public abstract class Animal { ...

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal { ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "mammals")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "mammal_id")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "dog")
public class Dog extends Mammal { ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "mammals")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "mammal_id")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "cat")
public class Cat extends Mammal { ...
```

So I have 2 tables: animals and mammals.
This configuration is working, unless I don't completely understand how.
The inheritance type is changed from JOINED to SINGLE_TABLE in Mammal, so  cats and dogs are stored in mammals table joined with animals table by mammal_id column.

The problem is that is not possible to retrieve a mammal (cat or dog) in a polymorphic way:

```
Mammal mammal = (Mammal) hibernateTemplate.get(Mammal.class, id);
```

or a list of mammals (dogs and cats) with a single Hibernate query:

```
List<Mammal> list = (List<Mammal>) hibernateTemplate.find("from Mammal");
```

I get: "Unknown entity: Mammal", because Mammal is not an entity, it is just a mapped super class.

I tried several changes in configuration for example the one below. This seems to make sense, but in that case I got "Could not load entity: Mammal" because it looks for tables cats and dogs (which doesn't exist).

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "animals")
public abstract class Animal { ...

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "mammals")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "mammal_id")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal { ...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "dog")
public class Dog extends Mammal { ...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "cat")
public class Cat extends Mammal { ...
```

So, to summarize: I want to keep the webapp working the same way (2 tables: animals and mammals) but at the same time be able to do a polymorphic query: retrieve a list of mammals (cats and dogs) with one query.

I hope I was clear enough and thanks in advance for any help.

ANOTHER TRY:

"Foreign key circularity dependency involving the following tables: "

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "animals")
public abstract class Animal { ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "mammals")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "mammal_id")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal { ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "mammals")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "dog")
public class Dog extends Mammal { ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "mammals")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "cat")
public class Cat extends Mammal { ...
```

Comment: how did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `hibernateTemplate.find("from Mammal")` ?

Your `find` query needs to be in terms of **JPA entities** not table names.

BTW tables are typically named in the singular - it generally makes complex queries read a bit better - e.g. `WHERE chicken.id = egg.id`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the query, that was just an example. This is a working  webapp, the data model is done. Actually I changed the entity names to make the example easier to follow (I hope).