# How to mix inheritance type in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, openjpa, jpa-2.1

How to mix single table type inheritance  with join table type in the same inheritance tree?
I'm not using hibernate just JPA.
I know there is  no official support for mixed inheritance by reading the JPA spec. 
I can't change the architecture. It did worked with hibernate but now I need to implement this using openjpa. 
I'm looking for some workaround.

Comment: You need to add some context. Can you post the code of what you are attempting?

Comment: JPA tells you clearly to specify the inheritance strategy in the root of the tree, and that is all there is. How exactly can you "mix" it with that constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working for me:

Superclass:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR")
public class A extends SomeClass implements SomeInteface {


…
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
public Integer getPk() {
    return super.getPk();
}
…
```

Notice that "SomeClass"  is not an entity.

Subclass  - "JOIN" inheritance:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "A_SECOND_TABLE", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name ="ID") )
@DiscriminatorValue("BD")
public class B extends A implements SomeIntefaceB {
…
```

Create a new table "A_SECOND_TABLE" with join on super class Primary Key "ID".
each field that is not in join column and appears in our table is marked like this:

```
@Basic
@Column(table = "A_SECOND_TABLE", name = "STATUS", nullable = false, precision = 0)
```

Notice the table value.

Subclass – single table inheritance:

```
@Entity
public class C extends A implements SomeIntefaceC {...
```

simple single table inheritance.